# JavaScript context in anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, scope, anonymous-function

I want to set a function as a property of each element in an array, but call it with different arguments. I thought I'd solve it using an anonymous function:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < object_count; i++ ) {
    objects[i].callback = function(e,x,y){ cb(e,x,y,i) };
}
```

However, the function is called with the value that `i` has at the time. How would I preserve the context?

Comment: Make `i` an argument instead of placing it in the function at declaration time?

Comment: Why do you provide `i` to `cb()` in the first place? the function will not be able to access other elements of the array unless it's a global array but in that case you wouldn't need this *per element* function.

Comment: @Brad: put that into an answer as Tim may be satisfied with your suggestion which does solve the problem, but he may have a different issue with his code.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @Brad: The callback function is called from a library which is out of my control, and so I cannot add an argument. @Robert: `cb()` stores the state of an object on the server-side, and the only relevant data to store are `x` and `y`.

Comment: @Robert: My assumption was there was a reason for it, I was more or less gathering input back as to why this wasn't already the case (thus I felt it wasn't an adequate answer).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wrap the assignment in a function, or the right-hand side at least:

```
    objects[i].callback = (function(i) { return function(e, x, y) {
      cb(e, x, y, i);
    })(i);
```

The "outer" anonymous function is called right away, copying the loop variable "i" into an argument (which I also called "i"; some think it's confusing to do that while others say it's confusing *not* to do it, so you can decide :-)  which is then used by the returned "inner" anonymous function.

Another approach to this problem would be to use a utility function for this purpose instead of a simple in-line anonymous function.  In this case, it's made slightly tricky because you want "i" to be the *last* parameter of the actual callback function. The [Functional](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/) JavaScript library has a cool utility that lets you "pre-populate" selected arguments of a function with fixed values, giving you a function that lets you pass in arguments to the non-fixed ones; it'd look something like this:

```
  objects[i].callback = (function(e, x, y, i) { return cb(e, x, y, i); }).partial(_, _, _, i);
```

Whether that's better or worse is a matter of style and opinion.

*edit* just had a little more coffee - I think that I was being a little silly thinking that I had to use "partial()" above. The fact that the inner (the "real" function) wants "i" at the end of the parameter list is really not relevant to the way things need to be set up. That above example could also be done like this:

```
   objects[i].callback = (function(i, e, x, y) { return cb(e, x, y, i); }).curry(i);
```

which is way less bizarre.  (Either would work however. At least, I think they would. :-)

Comment: +1 Though I'd prefer to create the outer anonymous function outside the `for` loop.

Comment: @lonesomeday - yes I agree; I would prefer to do this with `.bind()` or something like that. I'll add a mention of that to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is an elegant solution.

Comment: I'd tend to think that a named function in place of the anonymous one in the first example would be simpler while avoiding the performance penalty of the anonymous function.

Comment: I agree Patrick; I have a hard time forming aesthetic opinions about these things (well, maybe not with *forming* them, but with keeping consistent ones :-). An argument could be made that doing the functions in-line adds local clarity about what's going on and why, but I think it depends on the reader's own biases.

Comment: I understand your point. I see your `.curry()` update, and I should probably just take a look at the library, but I'm wondering about purpose of the `i` in the parameters list. `(function(i, e, x, y) {... ` Does it get sliced off the Arguments object or something? Or maybe it's getting wrapped in another function that calls it with that first argument?

Comment: @patrick dw - yes I think that's what happens. The "curry()" function returns a function with the first *n* arguments (however many were passed to "curry()") pre-set, sort of.  So when *that* function is called, the arguments at that point are passed in as the tail of that argument list. (It would be a lot clearer to just look at the code for it probably :-)

Comment: @Pointy: I'll check it out. As I remember, they've got that beautifully annotated source code, so I don't really have an excuse not to. :o)

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
for (var i = something; ...) {
  a[i] = function() { x(i); }
}
```

The `i` in your functions will be the same for all functions (it's the very same variable you define in the scope of your `for` loop.

What you want to do is to have a variable that's specific for each function context. You could do something like this

```
for (var i = something; ...) {
  (function () {        // using an anonymous function, we create a private context
     var new_i = i;     // new_i has the value of 'i' but exists solely in this
                        // private context
     a[i] = function() { x(new_i); }
                        // the assigned function now refers a variable of the private
                        // context, which will be different on the following loop
                        // iterations
  })();
}
```

You can get more information on this topic by searching how closures and scope work in JavaScript.

Comment: I think I like Pointy's solution better. It solves it in a very similar way but is shorter and wittier. ;) Still a +1 from me, because it does solve the problem as well.